# Query result null where in (array)

Tags: sql, join

table1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |

table2

| id_table1 | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | earth |
| 1 | sun |
| 2 | earth |

```
SELECT_
table1.id as id, 
table1.name as name, 
table2.detail as detail
FROM
table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id_table1 = table1.id
WHERE 
table2.detail in (1,2)
```

I want the result like in the following table

Result

| id | name | Detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | earth |
| 1 | AA | sun |
| 2 | BB | null |
| 2 | BB | earth |

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could think now is a clumsy one.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table1 (id int, name varchar(50));
 insert into table1 values(1,   'AAA');
 insert into table1 values(2,   'BBB');
 
 create table table2 (id_table1 int, Detail varchar(50));
 insert into table2 values(1,   'earth');
 insert into table2 values(1,   'sun');
 insert into table2 values(2,   'earth');
```

At first to get the non existing rows for a table id in table2 I have used not cross join with not exists

```
  select id,null Detail  from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2 
    where not exists
        (
           select 1 from table2 where t1.id=table2.id_table1 and t2.Detail=table2.Detail
        )
```

Output:

| id | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | *null* |

Then union it with table2 to before joining it with table1

Query:

```
 SELECT
 tbl1.id , 
 tbl1.name , 
 t.detail 
 from
 (
    select id,null Detail  from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2 
    where not exists
        (
           select 1 from table2 where t1.id=table2.id_table1 and t2.Detail=table2.Detail
        )
    union all
 
    select * from table2
 ) t
 left join table1 tbl1 on t.id=tbl1.id
```

Output:

| id | name | detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BBB | <emnull</em |
| 1 | AAA | earth |
| 1 | AAA | sun |
| 2 | BBB | earth |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79bba126a5deecee17dac82ddf50d7cc)*